# How can I cancel the figure numbering?

Tags: captions, minipage

My previous figure number is 11. And I am adding following figures and my expectation is getting fig 12. but my number is 14. How can eliminate the numbering of them?

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult} %special version 
   \usepackage{mathptmx}       % selects Times Roman as basic font
\usepackage{helvet}         % selects Helvetica as sans-serif font
\usepackage{courier}        % selects Courier as typewriter font
\usepackage{type1cm}        % activate if the above 3 fonts are
                            % not available on your system

\usepackage{epstopdf}       % Converts eps to pdf if your version of 
                            % Tex (or pdflatex) does not support eps

%
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}


\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
          \centering
            \caption*{example-image}
     \end{subfigure}
     \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
     \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
    \centering
       \caption*{example-image} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption*{Images include to example-image} 
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
     \begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
        \caption*{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
        \caption*{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption*{Images include example-image} 
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
     \centering
        \caption*{example-image}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
     \begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[h!]{\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
        \caption*{example-image}
    \end{subfigure} 
     \end{minipage}
    \caption*{Images include example-image} 
    \caption{Used grouped images with their features and their corresponding histograms}
    \label{fig:example-image}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: please make the code a complete document that people can debug (you can use `example-image` as the image as that is generally available)  (unrelated but avoid using `[h!]` on `figure` and I doubt it is legal at all on `subfigure` (which doesn't float anyway) also it is best to avoid using the figure numbers in `\label`

Comment: the `\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}` in each figure isn't doing anything as the `figure` is already a box of that width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the question, thanks!

Comment: it's still not something that can be run to see the problem, it needs `\documentclass` and you are leaving people to guess which packages are needed (I would guess at least `float` and `graphicx` but maybe others) please make the example complete from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` but no bigger than required to show the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle looks better? Thank you for your contribution. Let's solve my numbering problem :) I dont want to change minipage or converting all of them as subfigure.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about not wanting to change `minipage` since a minipage in that position does nothing. After your edit the file will generate multiple errors as `\documentclass` is after `\begin{document}` and do you _really_ need _all_ those packages to run the example. Please consider the people trying to debug this for you, adding unrelated packages just makes it harder to trace the code paths.

Comment: Why exactly are you using `caption*` almost everywhere?

Comment: Does `subfigure` really have placement specifiers? Seems completely pointless to me. But i haven't tried your example.

Comment: @Johannes_B No, `subfigure` has no placement specifiers. Instead it has the same syntax (including optional arguments) as `minipage` since `subfigure` is actually a `minipage` with the possibility of using `\caption`. Therefore the extra `minipage`s around the `subfigures` are redundant.

Comment: @axel Bad wording from me. h! is pointless.

Comment: BTW: Both `caption` and `subcaption` are incompatible to the `svmult` document class. `\captionsetup{compatibility=false}` is some kind of sledgehammer without a guarantee of success. So better try using `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `\caption*` (or `\subcaption*`, `\subcaption` or `\caption`) inside the subfigures steps the outer `figure` counter - this happens even in a standard `article` class, and is because it has no way of knowing whether the outer figure is numbered or not.  You can counteract this by a manual adjustment

```
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```

at the beginning of the outer figure (regardless of how many subfigures that figure contains).  In the code below I have applied that adjustment to the third figure, but not the first.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{Subfigure}
    \subcaption*{Test subcaption unnumbered}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip
    \fbox{Figure}
  \caption*{Test caption unnumbered}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{Subfigure}
    \subcaption*{Test subcaption unnumbered}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip
    \fbox{Figure}
  \caption{Test caption numbered}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{Subfigure}
    \subcaption*{Test subcaption unnumbered}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{Subfigure}
    \subcaption*{Test subcaption unnumbered}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip
    \fbox{Figure}
  \caption*{Test caption unnumbered}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{Subfigure}
    \subcaption*{Test subcaption unnumbered}
  \end{subfigure}

  \medskip
    \fbox{Figure}
  \caption{Test caption numbered}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```